# Ionic2 multiple components styling

Tags: mobile, sass, ionic2

I'm new to Ionic2, in the official documentation I found out that for further customization of Ionic2 components (like button, ion-input and the like), I need to use sass variables. But they are global variables and so they are applied to all elements. Is there a way to apply these variables only to same pages or to define different inputs with different styling provided by those sass variables?
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to apply little changes on the aspect of some elements, use simple CSS3 style files.

Comment: Thx Giorgio, in fact I found that with some proper css selector it's possible to change a lot of things in every ionic component. Unfortunaly there is no way to find out these without looking the code behind these component; so I don't know if these are best practices or just a workaround.